# What programmer do I select in Arduino IDE for the ATMEL-ICE ISP?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, isp, programmer

I have been using an AVRISPmkII for many years but recently gave mine away to another hobbiest. I wnated to buy a replacement and have had to buy an ATMEL-ICE ISP as the AVRISPmkII is now unavailable.

Occasionally, I like to program the Arduino Uno from the Arduino IDE using the ISP.

However when I go to select the programmer (from the tools menu), I don't see the ATMEL-ICE in the list.

How do I get Arduino IDE to recognize the ATMEL-ICE ISP?

Note: I am using Arduino IDE v1.6.8.

Comment: Is the AVRISP MKii unreliable because the 6-pin cable is worn out? I made a new one for mine with a new piece of ribbon cable and two header connectors. Might be able to reuse the same cable even, just cut it a little shorter at both ends. I think mine wore out at the plastic case end.  https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-icc-fci/71600-006LF/609-2841-ND/1302571

Comment: @CrossRoads Thanks for the information. I often give my programmers away (in a bundle of other Arduino bits and pieces) in an attempt to inspire more people to take up coding.

Comment: Atmel is no longer selling the AVRISP MKii. I'm holding onto mine! Still works great after changing the ribbon cable out.  Not too hard too split the case to unplug and plug a new one on.

Comment: @CrossRoads I am glad to hear that yours is working great, however, this is not the problem I am having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As of [V1.8.2](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software), the ATMEL-ICE is now included as a programmer in the Arduino IDE.**

The ATMEL-ICE was not available as a in-system programmer (ISP) in version 1.6.8 of the Arduino IDE.

---

On the 20th of Jan 2017, user facchinm added the ATMEL-ICE to the list of programmers in the IDE, and it was merged into the master on the 8th of Feb. It was [released as a version on the 22nd of March 2017](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/releases).